# Bool Tool Add-on missing option

Tags: add-on

Im following a tutorial using the ad-on Bool tool, and there's an option I dont have in my settings. I downloaded the current Blender version, but still dont get this option in my Bool tool option. Solver: Fast- Exact.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Exact* solver option will be introduced with the release of Blender 2.91 as documented by the [release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.91/Modeling). The design task for the boolean redesign was [T67744](https://developer.blender.org/T67744) and the commit that introduced this to the master branch [rB9e09b5c418c0a436e3c84ccf38c065527988b0a0](https://developer.blender.org/rB9e09b5c418c0a436e3c84ccf38c065527988b0a0).

The release of Blender 2.91 is planned for the end of November 2020. You can download the daily builds of the beta version from [builder.blender.org](https://builder.blender.org/download/).

Comment: Ah OK, i missed that part, Cheers!